# How to allow ssh into a device on remote 4g modem when provider is blocking inbound connections?

Tags: firewall, ssh

I am planning on deploying a network of remote devices, each connected to the internet through a 4G modem.  The devices need both outbound connectivity to our cloud-based servers, and occasional inbound SSH connectivity for troubleshooting/maintenance.

The provider with the widest coverage offers 3 basic options:

- A non-routable dynamic IP address. (default)
- A "private" static IP address.
- A "public" static IP address.

As I understand it, both "private" and "public" addresses are routable, but the private ones are behind a firewall which blocks all inbound connections.  The  advantage is that we wouldn't pay for the data usage of the constant random port scanning and break-in attempts that occur (and get blocked by our own firewall).   The disadvantage is that it blocks our attempts to SSH into the device on demand.

Is there a mechanism that can allow ssh on demand to the device, but won't run afoul of the inbound connection blocking?  Perhaps something that runs on bootup of the remote system?  Ideally it wouldn't suck up gobs of data keeping a connection alive 24/7.

Comment: Have you tried asking your ISP to open up these ports?

Comment: The ISP is Verizon Wireless - they don't do anything you ask them.

Answer (score 2):

As you're behind a firewall you don't control, the only way to get through it is from the inside out.  The simplest solution is having your firewall within it create a VPN tunnel to a known point, where you could then access the systems inside your firewall directly.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a TOR hidden service to access it. The latency would be higher than doing a vpn connection, as stated above, due to the packet going around the world. The vpn would be far better from a management standpoint, since with TOR your device would be at the mercy of the independent TOR relays.